# Create link as we navigate inside menu bar?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hyperlink, navigation

we have requirement currently as shows in below image.

have googled much but i don't have specific key word so i couldn't find any thing.

we have a requirement to display link in navigation bar so user can select appropriate page without going forth and back ...by directly selecting the required page link.

how could it be possible to do inside asp.net as i have shows in image below.

Thank you so much........
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at `Navigation` here http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp and `Site Map` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx

As basic as it can be, you can use a list on the pages where you want to show links.
Let's say you have three pages A, B and C. On each page add a list like below.

So you go about like this

```
<span>You are here</span>
<ul id="navList" runat="server">
</ul>
```

On page A's codebehind add the following to your list.

```
HyperLink nav=new HyperLink();
nav.NavigateUrl="A.aspx";//You can also pass parameters here.
HtmlGenericControl li=new HtmlGenericControl("<li>");
HtmlGenericControl span=new HtmlGenericControl("<span>");
span.InnerText=">>";
li.Controls.Add(span);
li.Controls.Add(nav);
navList.Controls.Add(li);
```

Similarly for B

```
HyperLink nav=new HyperLink();
nav.NavigateUrl="A.aspx";//You can also pass parameters here.
HtmlGenericControl li=new HtmlGenericControl("<li>");
HtmlGenericControl span=new HtmlGenericControl("<span>");
span.InnerText=">>";
li.Controls.Add(span);
li.Controls.Add(nav);
navList.Controls.Add(li);

HyperLink nav2=new HyperLink();
nav2.NavigateUrl="B.aspx";//You can also pass parameters here.
HtmlGenericControl li2=new HtmlGenericControl("<li>");
HtmlGenericControl span2=new HtmlGenericControl("<span>");
span2.InnerText=">>";
li2.Controls.Add(span);
li2.Controls.Add(nav);
navList.Controls.Add(li2);
```

And similarly for C.

Comment: it should be create dynamically as we navigate inside left-side tree view. will above code do that? thank you so much for answering

Comment: Have a look at the first link, they have got exactly what you need.

Comment: ok thanks you so much... is there any specific name for this kind of link(Product>>Item Kits>>Item Groups)??... suggest me more links if possible.....

Comment: Its called SiteMapPath. Google for "ASP.NET SiteMapPath", you will see a lot of useful links.

Comment: If I was of help, please mark my answer and close the question.